# foreach to linq with guid comparison

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, guid

I would like to convert the foreach in this method to a linq expression.  I have 2 try/catches because I can't always count on the strings that are passed in the list of guids or guidToFind to be valid guid strings.

```
    public static bool IsGuidInList(List<string> guids, string guidToFind)
    {
        try
        {
            var guid = new Guid(guidToFind.Trim());
            foreach (var g in guids)
            {
                try
                {
                    var g2 = new Guid(g.Trim());
                    if (g2 == guid)
                        return true;
                }
                catch {} // swallow exception
            }
        }
        catch{} // swallow exception
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You guys are fast with the responses.  And, sorry, I modified the original method to include a second try/catch...This is so that if one of the strings in the list is no good, meaning it can't be cast to a guid, the method doesn't immediately exit with false.  It should attempt all items in list.

Comment: Is empty Guid could be in string's list of Guids?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static bool IsGuidInList(List<string> guids, string guidToFind)
{
    try
    {
        var guid = new Guid(guidToFind.Trim());
        return
            guids
            .Select(x =>
            {
                Guid result;
                return Guid.TryParse(x, out result) ? (Guid?)result : null;
            })
            .Where(x => x.HasValue)
            .Any(x => x.Value == guid);
    }
    catch { } // swallow exception
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need it to do.  It returns true if guidToFind is in the list, returns false if not, and any bad guid strings in the list are handled with the GuidTryParse.  One improvement is to do away with the try / catch in this block and do a TryParse on the guidToFind.  I will try doing that.

Comment: @Kershaw I agree that is a better approach and considered including that in my answer but it seemed beyond the scope of the question so I only implemented the LINQ.

Answer (score 6):

```
   var tg = Guid.Empty; 
   guids.Any(g=> g!= null 
       && Guid.TryParse(g.Trim(), out tg) && new Guid(g.Trim()) == guid)
```

Comment: This is nice and tight, and works great unless one of the guid strings in the list is invalid.  I would recommend this as a valid answer if you knew all of the passed in guid strings and guidToFind string were valid.

Comment: @Kershaw, you should use `TryParse` instead of catching and swallowing exception which is ugly

Comment: You should use `TryParse` for the first conversion as well

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not particularly different to the others already posted, but I would personally use this:

```
    public static bool ContainsGuid(this IEnumerable<string> guids, string guidToFind)
    {
        if (guids == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(guids));
        if (guidToFind == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(guidToFind));

        if (!Guid.TryParse(guidToFind, out var guid)) 
            throw new ArgumentException($"Could not convert '{guidToFind}' to a GUID");

        return guids
            .Select(s => Guid.TryParse(s, out var result) ? (Guid?)result : null)
            .Contains(guid);
    }
```

The differences being:

- extension method (personal preference)
- newer C# features e.g. 'out var result' (personal preference)
- explicitly validating parameters (depends on the behaviour you are after, but I'm a big fan)

The last item leads me to a general point:
If your program is taking as input a collection of strings that are meant to be GUIDs, why not validate those at the time and keep an IEnumerable of Guid? Do the same thing for the GUID to find and the code becomes:

```
IEnumerable<Guid> guidList = // validated elsewhere
var found = guidList.Contains(guid);
```

Comment: I like what you've done with throwing relevant exceptions, which could be useful if it were desired.  But in this particular case, I don't care to know what went wrong, I just want to know if guidToFind is in list, and if passed in guidToFind is invalid, just return false.  This is certainly a valid answer, in the right context.

Answer (score 1):

Thx for the great answers, however I went with Jason Boyds answer, but with a slight modification of my own to get rid of the last try/catch.  I have run these tests with the results I expected:

- bad guidToFind string
- good guidToFind string, list of all valid guid strings
- good guidToFind string, list of mostly valid guid strings

  ```
  public static bool IsGuidInList(List<string> guids, string guidToFind)
  {
      Guid guid;
      if (!Guid.TryParse(guidToFind.Trim(), out guid))
          return false;

      return
          guids
              .Select(x =>
              {
                  Guid result;
                  return Guid.TryParse(x, out result) ? (Guid?)result : null;
              })
              .Where(x => x.HasValue)
              .Any(x => x.Value == guid);
  }
  ```

UPDATE:
After feedback from a code review with the above method, I was able to make more refinements and this is the result:

```
    public static bool IsGuidInList(IEnumerable<string> guids, string guidToFind)
    {
        Guid guid;
        if (!Guid.TryParse(guidToFind.Trim(), out guid))
            return false;

        return guids.Any(x => { Guid result;
            Guid.TryParse(x, out result);
            return result == guid;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

not as terse as the other solution, but I find it readable

```
    public static bool IsGuidInList(List<string> guids, string guidToFind)
    {
        Guid outGuid;

        var inGuidToFind = Guid.TryParse(guidToFind, out outGuid) ? outGuid : Guid.Empty;
        if (inGuidToFind == Guid.Empty)
            return false;

        var inGuids = new List<Guid>();
        guids.Where(i => Guid.TryParse(i, out outGuid)).ForEach(i => inGuids.Add(new Guid(i)));

        return inGuids.Contains(inGuidToFind);
    }
```